# The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, assets, archive

I've looked at other questions with the same issue and did what was suggested in them but keep getting the same error.

I've dragged 120x120 file into my project, cleaned, built, archived, same error. 
I've dragged 120x120 file into the asset catalog manually, cleaned, built, archived, same error.

Here's a pic of my asset appicon:

[image]

There is no drag and drop for 120x120. Where am I suppose to add it?

Thanks

Comment: I may be out of limb here but which devices are you supporting?...

Comment: iPhone only....

Comment: Then why have you added appicons only for iPad as per screen

Comment: Those were the only options presented to me. I resolved it, you have to go into the info plist and add the path to the 120x120 icon.

Answer (score 2):

Dont drag images in asset.

Go to this link - https://makeappicon.com

Upload your 1024 image, it will email you the icons for iOS and Android as well.

Just copy and paste AppIcon.appiconset file into bundle.

Comment: That what I did, in the AppIcon.appiconset there's no 120x120 file.

Comment: there is Icon-App-60x60@2x in that folder which is the same file that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have already solved this, but I'd like to share an observation about this topic as I'm currently struggling with the same problem.

When you generate an app icon set with tools like makeappicon.com, chances are that not all possible icon variants are created. For example, old icon sizes (for iOS 5/6) are probably not produced.

In Xcode's assets editor (at least in Xcode 8.2.1) you only see the slots for which an icon is provided; for me this led to the misinterpretation that all possible icons are present. However, if you manually add an empty icon set in Xcode ("+" -> "New iOS App Icon"), you will see that there are more possible slots then are filled by the icon tool.

In my case the problem was that the deployment target was set to iOS6, but some icons required for iOS6 were not included in the icon set; so I created a new, empty icon set, manually dragged in the files which were created by my icon tool, and then created the missing icons by hand.